# A program that counts how many prime numbers are between 2 and a given number

Tags: primes

I've just had one of my exams at the college
one of the questions were to program a function that counts how many prime numbers are between 2 and a given number from the user(including the number).
I wrote this algorithm which works for me but they still deducted all of the points of the question as if it was completely wrong.
Can please someone tell me what's wrong with the code?
Thanks a lot.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int count = 0;
    int num;
    cout << "Please enter a natural number " << endl;
    cin >> num;

    for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++)
    {
        if ((i == 2 || i == 3 || i == 5||i == 7) || (i % 3 != 0 & i % 5 != 0 & i % 7 != 0 & i % 2 != 0))
            count++;
    }
    cout << "There are " << count << " prime numbers beteween 2 amd " << num << endl;
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 0):

Your code only checks if a number is a multiple of 2, 3, 5, or 7. That's missing a lot of multiples, meaning your code likely gives many false positives.

That condition is also quite difficult to read, so you probably would have lost points for that as well.

You would have been much better off replacing that condition in the loop with another `for` loop, and checking every odd number from 3 to the square root of the test number.